# While loop is not iterating on whole dataset

Tags: python, while-loop

I am using below code to for a while loop however its not iterating on whole data. may I know where am I wrong-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from hurst import compute_Hc

df = pd.read_csv("AARTIIND.csv")
df['Hurst'] = np.nan
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

j=0
i=105
while i <= len(df)+1:
    df['Hurst'].iloc[i-1] = compute_Hc(df['Close'][j:i], kind='price')[0]
    j=j+1
    i=i+1
    print (df.head(108))
    break
```

Comment: Remove the `break` statement, or you'll always break out of the loop on the first iteration

Comment: A general advice: Think about iterating over the dataframe. This is considered as bad practice in most cases and might be avoided by using the `df.apply()` method.

Comment: `while i <= len(df)+1` is usually written as `while i < len(df)` or `for i in range(105, len(df)):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can work better if you remove the "break" line 16

Comment: If I remove break, I get this error message-  single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: @MohitGarg That's because `i` will be too large, on your last iteration, for `i - 1` to be an index of your DataFrame. Debugging and printing out values on each iteration will help you spot things like this.